# what exactly is the danger of an uninitialized pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

I am trying get a handle on C as I work my way thru Jim Trevor's "[Cyclone: A safe dialect of C](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/cyclone/papers/cyclone-safety.pdf)" for a PL class. Trevor and his co-authors are trying to make a safe version of C, so they eliminate uninitialized pointers in their language. [Googling around a bit](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c25.htm) on uninitialized pointers, it seems like un-initialized pointers point to random locations in memory. It seems like this alone makes them unsafe. If you reference an un-itilialized pointer, you jump to an unsafe part of memory. Period. But the way Trevor talks about them seems to imply that it is more complex. He cites the following code, and explains that when the function FrmGetObjectIndex dereferences f, it isn’t accessing a valid pointer, but rather an unpredictable address — whatever was on the stack when the space for f was allocated.

What does Trevor mean by "whatever was on the stack when the space for f was allocated"? Are "un-initialized" pointers initialized to random locations in memory by default? Or does their "random" behavior have to do with the memory allocated for these pointers getting filled with strange values (that are then referenced) because of unexpected behavior on the stack.

```
Form *f;
   switch (event->eType) {
   case frmOpenEvent:
   f = FrmGetActiveForm(); ...
   case ctlSelectEvent:
   i = FrmGetObjectIndex(f, field); ...
}
```

Comment: If event->eType is ctlSelectEvent, then f will be uninitialized, which is the original point. I don't get your question. 'case' works much like 'goto'.

Comment: Any variable which is not initialized has an **Indeterminate** value, same is true for pointers.They can point to any random indeterminate address.There is no default behavior.Only behavior is indetreminate and using indeterminate values results in Undefined behavior.

Comment: Uninitialized pointers are not initialized at all - not to NULL, not to random values. If you have a routine f() which has one local int variable that has a value of 0xDEADBEEF, exit the routine, then call a routine g() which has one local int* variable that you don't otherwise initialize, then the int* is pointing at the location 0xDEADBEEF. A good outcome is a crash; a bad outcome is a security hole - unintended access to memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does Trevor mean by "whatever was on the stack when the space for f was allocated"?

He means that in most assembly languages, separate instructions are used to reserve space on the stack and to write an initial value inside the newly reserved space. If a C program uses an uninitialized variable, the program will **typically** at run-time execute the instruction that reserves stack space but no instruction that sets it. When the pointer is used, it will literally contain the bit pattern that was on the stack before space was reserved. In the good cases this will be an invalid address. In the bad cases this will happen to be a valid address, and the effects will be unpredictable.

This is only a typical behavior. From the theoretical point of view, using an indeterminate value is *undefined behavior*. Much stranger things than simply accessing an invalid address or a valid one can happen (examples with uninitialized data (not addresses) used [accidentally](http://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/) or [purposely](http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/)).

---

Here is the sort of dangers that a restricted subset of C such as Cyclone aims to prevent:

```
int a, *p;

int main(int c, char **v){
  int l, *lp, i;
  if (c & 1) 
    a = l + 1;      // danger
  if (c & 2)
    *lp = 3;        // danger
  if (c & 4)
    {
      p = &a;  
      for (i=0; i<=1; i++)
        {
          int block_local;
          *p = 4;   // danger
          p = &block_local;
        }
    }
}
```

In the last dangerous line, in practice, it is most likely that 4 will be written to variable `block_local`, but in reality, at the second iteration, `p` is indeterminate, the program is not supposed to access `*p`, and it is undefined behavior when it does.

Comment: +1. To be sure, invalid addresses are the good case since they'll cause the program to crash quickly (with a segfault) instead of go on to produce faulty results.

Comment: is the stack "wiped" clean (to all 0s) when a frame is popped? if i have an int var on the stack, pop the frame, add a new frame, is the old "bit pattern" from the old int variable still there--even if a new frame has be allocated to the same physical place in memory?

Comment: @akh2103 Typically, no, the stack is never wiped. A particular compiler could choose to generate the costly instructions that make it so. In practice, the makers of C compilers focus on speed of the generated code (which is more or less consistent with what C programmers expect from them). C compilers almost never initialize or clean-up memory when they do not have to.

Comment: OK. So the stack is never wiped. So you allocate memory for a pointer and the bit pattern on the stack could point to any random address. That is the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

On modern OS's the danger is a core dump. On earlier systems without memory management and possibly memory mapped i/o to external HW the dangers are of completely different magnitude.