# segment fault in single function mergesort of linked list

Tags: c++

I am running into a segmentation fault from using the online C++ compiler while doing this single function mergesort all day and I couldn't locate where it possibly be. The other problem is that the way that I don't understand this method of finding the mid of the linked list, why is it assignment operator, is there a better way to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listnode { struct listnode * next; int key; };

struct listnode * sort(struct listnode * a)
{
    struct listnode  *fast, *slow, *mid, *left, *right;
    fast = a; left = a; right = NULL;  mid = NULL;

    //data is null or one node
    if (!a || !a->next)
    {
        return a;
    }

    //find mid by declaring a pointer skipping throw an extra node for each loop

    while (fast)
    {
        if (fast = fast->next) { fast = fast->next; }
        mid = slow;
        slow = slow->next;
    }

    //split the list in recursion
    if (mid != NULL) { mid->next = NULL; }

    a = sort(a); slow = sort(slow);

    //merge
    while (left != NULL && slow != NULL)
    {
        if (left->key < right->key) { left->next = mid; right = left; }
        else
        {
            if (!right)
                a = slow;
            else
            {
                right = slow; right->next = slow;  slow = slow->next; right->next = left;
            }
        }

    }
    if (left == NULL) { right->next = slow; }
    return(a);

}


//test 


int main()
{
    long i;
    struct listnode *node, *tmpnode, *space;
    space = (struct listnode *) malloc(500000 * sizeof(struct listnode));
    for (i = 0; i< 500000; i++)
    {
        (space + i)->key = 2 * ((17 * i) % 500000);
        (space + i)->next = space + (i + 1);
    }
    (space + 499999)->next = NULL;
    node = space;
    printf("\n prepared list, now starting sort\n");
    node = sort(node);
    printf("\n checking sorted list\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        if (node == NULL)
        {
            printf("List ended early\n"); exit(0);
        }
        if (node->key != 2 * i)
        {
            printf("Node contains wrong value\n"); exit(0);
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("Sort successful\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger, it will tell you where the segmentation fault is and you can use it to step through the program to see what goes wrong. This is also C, not C++. And there is `malloc` without `free` which almost surely is a problem but at least extremely bad habit.

Comment: ... and please use proper C++ code and containers. This abuse of pointers is going to give me nightmares for at least a week.

Comment: ... or use C tag. This code seems to be written in plain C and compiles well with C compilers.

Comment: my visual studio fails to compile the project the second time I open it so i had to test the code with online compiler. The test code was originally C so I only modified a little bit to test it .

Comment: "if (fast = fast->next)" do you mean equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one problem is:

```
while (fast)
{
    if (fast = fast->next) { fast = fast->next; }
    mid = slow;
    slow = slow->next; // <-------- HERE!
}
```

`fast` was assigned to non-null value before this loop, so control enters the loop and tries to read `slow->next`, which is invalid. The `slow` pointer was not assigned to anything before the loop, so it holds garbage value and does not point to valid memory location. Thus, reading memory by this pointer is very likely to violate process address space. And from the language perspective, reading an uninitialized pointer is an example of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

See also a good explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347880/what-exactly-is-the-danger-of-an-uninitialized-pointer-in-c) question.

Comment: @user6820297 OK, now it fails to read memory by one if the pointers in this condition: `if (left->key < right->key)`. It happens on the 12th recursive call of `sort`. Please use a debugger and/or memory profiler to fix such bugs.